# Get wrapping element by XPath

Tags: html, dom, xpath

I have this markup:

```
<div class="whatever">
    <input id="uniqueId" type="checkbox">
    <label for="uniqueId">best label ever</label>
</div>
```

Of course, I can get the input via its `id` with *XPath*

```
//div[contains(@class, 'whatever')]/input[@id='uniqueId']
```

but how to target the wrapping `div`? There might be several of them, all with `class="whatever"`.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you have two conditions here: the `contains` one and the descendant one. You need to combine them with `and`:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'whatever') and input[@id='uniqueId']]
```

Comment: Running the risk of being nit-picking, you could shorten the expression by leaving away `./`.

Comment: @MathiasMüller You're quite right, of course. (And if you can't be nit-picky on StackOverflow, what's the point?)

Comment: Also, I was able to get the element by using: `//div[contains(@class, 'whatever')]/input[@id='uniqueId']/..`